# Play sound on both computers during a remote connection session?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, audio

Is it possible to hear sounds coming from the remote computer on both the remote computer itself and the computer connecting to it at the same time?

For example, in Windows Remote Desktop you seem to have these options:

1. Sounds on remote machine play on remote machine
2. Sounds on remote machine play on your local machine
3. Sounds on remote machine do not play anywhere

I'm looking for #4: Sounds on remote machine play both remotely and locally

Is this possible with Windows Remote Desktop, or any other software of that nature ([LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com/), etc)?

I'm running Windows 7 on both machines, if that makes a difference.

Thanks.

Comment: If this was intended as a programming question, it is extremely badly formed, since it mentions nothing about the technology you would want to use or any conding or installation limits. I (and some others) have therefore assumes you are asking for a piece of software, and voted to move it to SuperUser where you may get more help.

Comment: You probably wouldn't want this on a normal RDP session, unless you don't care that the local user won't be able to see what (on-screen) is making the sound.

Answer (score 0):

The sound will play on both computers with [logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/http://).